# Set the rest of the bits to 1 in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I need some help with bitwise operations.
I have number(64 bit) were first 16 bits are meaningful, and I'd like to set rest of them to "1"

***00000000 11000001 00000000 00000000 ...*** <- currrent value

***00000000 11000001 11111111 11111111 ...*** <- result I am trying to achieve

P.S. Oh, yeah! Sometimes, to solve - you just need to write out your task:)

I got it: **value |= (-1 << bitsCount);**

bitsCount - count of my meaningful bits

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You say your number is 64 bits, then you give 32 bit values.  Which is it?

Comment: Please clarify which bits in your diagram are the 'first' bits. Tell us the base-10 value of 'current value'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the bitwise OR operator:

```
value |= 0xFFFF
```

`1111111111111111`<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>16</sup> - 1= `FFFF`<sub>16</sub>

Answer (score 2):

OR it with `11111111 11111111`. `foo | 0xffff`